# Passing object/array from main method in array merge program

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm in a bit of trouble with this code.Please help.

I am trying to write a code to merge two arrays in ascending order.I've written the data members and the function to sort two arrays in ascending.

*Now I don't know how to write the main method which can input two arrays and then pass them as objects to the arrange() method.Can someone please show how to write the main method in this case.*

I've tried for a long time but all of them are causing errors.I've actually just started learning java by myself,so please don't mind if my question sounds silly.Thanks a lot!

---

```
public class MergeArrays
{
    int a1[];int size;
    MergeArrays(int n)
    {
        size=n;
        a1=new int[n];
    }
    void arrange(MergeArrays obj)
    {
        int answer[]=new int[obj.a1.length+a1.length];
        int i,j,k=0;
        while(i<size && j<obj.size)
        {
          if(a1[i]>obj.a1[j])
          {
              answer[k++]=obj.a1[j++];
           }
          else 
          {
              answer[k++]=a1[i++];
          }
        }
        while(i<size)
        {
            answer[k++]=a1[i++];
         }
        while(j<size)
        {
            answer[k++]=obj.a1[j++];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with minimal changes to your code.  As you have it, it would be best to create a main method in a separate class, and create two `MergeArrays` objects in there.

Note that your algorithm will only work on two sorted arrays.

I changed the `MergeArrays` constructor to take `varargs` in order to initialize the array in each object.

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //create two MergeArrays objects
    MergeArrays obj1 = new MergeArrays(1, 5, 10, 15, 20);
    MergeArrays obj2 = new MergeArrays(3, 7, 13, 18, 23);

    //get answer from arrange()
    int[] answer = obj1.arrange(obj2);

    //print the answer
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
     System.out.println(answer[i]); 
    }
  }
}


public class MergeArrays
{
    int a1[];int size;

    //used varargs here to send in the array
    MergeArrays(Integer... args)
    {
      size=args.length;
      a1=new int[size];

      //initialize 
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       a1[i] = args[i]; 
      }
    }

    int[] arrange(MergeArrays obj)
    {
        int answer[]=new int[obj.a1.length+a1.length];
        int i = 0; //initialize
        int j = 0; //initialize
        int k=0;
        while(i<size && j<obj.size)
        {
          if(a1[i]>obj.a1[j])
          {
              answer[k++]=obj.a1[j++];
          }
          else 
          {
              answer[k++]=a1[i++];
          }
        }
        while(i<size)
        {
            answer[k++]=a1[i++];
         }
        while(j<size)
        {
            answer[k++]=obj.a1[j++];
        }

        return answer; //add this
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
3
5
7
10
13
15
18
20
23
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that old Java programmers mantra?  If you didn't learn it as `public static void main( String args[])` then that is likely your problem.  If you want to do a simple command line program that runs once, merging two arrays together, leaving the final array in ascending order, then you have to grab that `String args[]`.  When a program is run from the command line, it's given a set of (space-separated) parameters, often denoted by a - followed by some letter.  The way the program grabs hold of these is through the `String args[]` of main, or some similar mechanism if it's in a different language.  In order to use these correctly, you need to assume some type of format that will allow you to distinguish the end of the first array from the beginning of the second.  A possible method is to expect that each array is a single parameter, made up of comma-separated values for each element.  The format for running this would be `"1,2,3,4,5" "6,7,8,9,0"` at the end of the command that starts the program.  You can then split each string up, using `String.split(",")` and you'll be left with the two arrays.  Another method would be to expect the format of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` except use a special string to denote the end of the first array, so more like `1 2 3 4 break 5 6 7 8`, and in that case you'd just iterate through, adding values to the first array until you reach break, then put the rest in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two arrays to be sorted, then use a method which receives two parameters and returns the merged one. So your main class should be something like...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {9,7,5,3,1};
    int[] array2 = {2,4,6,8,10};
    int[] merge = Merge.merge(array1, array2);
    System.out.println(merge);
}
```

Notice the *Merge* class with the *merge* method in my sample